# .apk upload successful but launch intent results in ClassNotFoundException com.game.demo.helloworld

Tags: java, android, android-intent, classnotfoundexception

I setup Eclipse IDE with Cocos2dx library.  I am trying to setup and run the helloworld project in the cocos2dx library but I am encountering this error in the LogCat after the helloworld.apk is uploaded to emulator successfully.

I'm on SDK 17
Eclipse Build: v22.0.1-685705

I've looked through almost 4-5 similar postings on stackoverflow but have tried everything and not sure how to fix this.

Here's the LogCat entries:

```
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.game.demo/com.game.demo.helloworld}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.demo.helloworld" on path: /data/app/com.game.demo-2.apk
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.demo.helloworld" on path: /data/app/com.game.demo-2.apk
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  ... 11 more
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.game.demo/com.game.demo.helloworld}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.demo.helloworld" on path: /data/app/com.game.demo-2.apk
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.demo.helloworld" on path: /data/app/com.game.demo-2.apk
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-26 06:30:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.game.demo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">

        <activity android:name=".helloworld"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the first line of helloworld.java (the one starting with `package`)

Comment: First line in helloworld.java is: package com.game.demo.helloworld;     This matches the android:name tag value in the AndroidManifest.xml.  But I think I am just referencing the package incorrectly?  Let me update screenshot of the project...maybe that will help...

Comment: I don't have enough points to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest package is declared as `com.game.demo`, but your file is in `com.game.demo.helloworld`.

Try:

```
<activity android:name="com.game.demo.helloworld.helloworld"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error yesterday, also no success with all the answers provided on SO.
What I finally found out:

I had used a "ViewPager" everywhere in the Code.

But then in the .xml-file that was used I accidentially typed "viewPager" - of course that one couldnt be found.

Also, as I found out today in the hard way - double check the package name of your objects you use in the .xml, if there are some.

Answer (score 0):

Did you export the cocos2dx jar with the apk? If that's not the case, it'll compile, but crash.